# How can we extend a packet in the case of an overflow?

Tags: java, overflow, counter, packet

I have frames sized with a fixed size of 7 values (t_i, i in {1..7}).
Each value is stored on 2 bytes (the max value is then = 2^(16) -1 = 65 535) and is divided by a resolution factor of 10000, which makes 6.5535ms as the maximum value (0xFFFF). Beyond those values, the 2 bytes are no longer enough and the counter overflows.

In my test cases, I often encounter overflow especially when I use quite low frequencies

> eg: frequency = 400Hz and t_1 = 1ms => t_7 = 1 + 6 * 1/400 = 16 ms >
> 6.5535 ms

To handle this overflow, what has been done until now was that that we **allowed the overflow** as it was detectable during the decoding.

To detect this overflow, the time delta between 2 consecutive (t_i) has been calculated to see if the result was lower than the max value (0xFFFF equivalent to 6.5535 ms)  in which case, there is an overflow (counter and growing by definition, a decay shows an anomaly ).

I am thinking about extending the frame (x2) in case of overflow. How can I proceed to do so?

Existing lines to bypass the counter's overflow problem :

```
    if (timeCounterInMs > 2000000000) { // 2000000000 is the value to be substracted to  the counter to transform long into double
                timeCounterInMs -= 2000000000;
                isCounterOverFlow = true;
    } else {
                isCounterOverFlow = false;
            }

     currentIndexInBytes += 4;
     body[index++] = timeCounterInMs; // body of the frame
            
     for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) { 
                long timeInTimeRatio = /*transform bytes to long*/;

                currentIndexInBytes += 2;
                body[index++] = timeInTimeRatio; 

                if (timeInTimeRatio == 0 && j != 0) {
                    // the end of the packet
                } else {
                    
                    if (timeInTimeRatio <= theLastValueInPacket && j != 0) { // If the time counter declay => overflow and start to zero

                        timeInTimeRatio = timeInTimeRatio + 65536; // 0xFFFF = 65536
                    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is a "frame"?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the kind of frame you're talking about, but looking at its description the frame tag doesn't seem appropriate. Given how specific your question is I think you should spend more time trying to find a relevant tag which would likely increase your chances of getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Aaron! Frame here, in the tag, refers indeed to something else, sorry ^^ I'll change it.

@chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-, a frame is like a container carrying a unit of data for networking. I could have used packet instead of frame in my case maybe

Comment: If this is some sort of custom data structure, we have no way of knowing what "serious repercussions" there could possibly be without a _lot_ more detail about the application.

Comment: I'll try then to write some reproductible code with the question